# Trying to match Javascript regex group after slash and other optional slash and rest of string

Tags: javascript, regex

How to match `some-blog-slug` in all scenarios below:

- `/blog/some-blog-post-slug/whatever/anything` (CASE 0)
- `/blog/some-blog-post-slug/whatever` (CASE 1)
- `/blog/some-blog-post-slug/`         (CASE 2)
- `/blog/some-blog-post-slug`          (CASE 3)

I'm trying: `^/\/blog\/([^\/]+)/`

But it's not working at all.

[image]

I need to match `some-blog-post` so I can extract it from the string.

PS.: Sorry to post another REGEX question here on SO.

Comment: I think it works. Did you enable the global flag? `g` at the right top of regex101 https://regex101.com/r/nVUh47/1

Comment: That's it! Thank you!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try out this code using `exec()` and `substring()` method .

```js
var re = /\//g,
  str = "/blog/some-blog-post-slug/whatever/anything"; //You can try out all the cases you mentioned in the question . 
var arr = [];
while ((match = re.exec(str)) != null) {
  arr.push(match.index);
  console.log("match found at " + match.index);
}
console.log(arr)
if (arr.length >= 3) {
  var str = str.substring(arr[1] + 1, arr[2]);
  console.log(str)
} else {
  var str = str.substring(arr[1]);
  console.log(str)
}
```

Check my code in this **[LINK](https://jsfiddle.net/ehtp73xo/)**

Comment: Thanks! I've thought of that. But even though I hate regex, I really think it's much cleaner to use it.

Comment: Yaa , Hope my solution gets useful to you . Happy to help you . Happy codding . @c

Comment: If you find my answer youful , it would be a great if you accept my answer . @cbdev420

Comment: Sorry sir , i mean it to `exec()` . Let me update it . Thank you sir for correcting me . @CodeManiac

Comment: But for me , anyone who teach me or correct me is meant to sir . :) @CodeManiac

Comment: @PushprajsinhChudasama you can turn your code into a [`running snippet`](https://stackoverflow.blog/2014/09/16/introducing-runnable-javascript-css-and-html-code-snippets/)

Comment: Edited . Thank you so much . @CodeManiac

Comment: @PushprajsinhChudasama you can create a running snippet on SO itself,  i have changed your code to snippet, read the link shared in last comment for more info

Comment: Okk sir , now got your point correctly , This advice will matter much for my growth . Once again thank you so much sir . @CodeManiac